# what is the the value of $\frac{a^2}{b+c}+\frac{b^2}{c+a}+\frac{c^2}{a+b}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $\frac{a}{a+i}+\frac{b}{b+1}+\frac{c}{c+1}=1$ then what is the the value of $\frac{a^2}{b+c}+\frac{b^2}{c+a}+\frac{c^2}{a+b}$

here I got $a=0$ and $bc=1$, when $ bc\neq 0$ but then I cant progress.

In which way should I go to find the value?

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ real?

Comment: that is not provided in the question. @Asvin

Comment: I am probably being dumb but how did you get $a = 0$ otherwise?

Comment: I was wrong @Asvin, I've taken a,b,c real.If a,b,c is real then what would be the value?

Comment: Are they positive?

Comment: Is that $a+1$ or $a+i$

Comment: It is given a+i @AkshayBodhare

Comment: It is not given they are positive or not @G-man

Comment: Since you have that $b \neq 0$, $c \neq 0 $, we have $bc = 1 \Leftrightarrow b^2/c = b/c^2$

Comment: @ROBINSON: $\frac{a^2}{b+c}+\frac{b^2}{c+a}+\frac{c^2}{a+b}=b^3+\frac{1}{b^3}$ cannot be constant where $b\not=0, b\not=-1$.